# How to create a List of Values based on a other List of Values?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

A oracle-apex question. I already have a static List of Values (LOV) named STATUS.

STATUS:

SEQUENCE DISPLAY RETURN

1 Example1 Example1

2 Example2 Example2

3 Example3 Example3

4 Example4 Example4

Now based on the first selection in LOV1 (STATUS), I want a second list LOV2 (EXTRA), to show one of the value sets:

1 (if you select Example1) =>  showing solution1, solution2 and solution3 in LOV2

2 => solution4 and solution5

How can I display the right options in LOV2, based on the selection in LOV1?

Comment: The second LOV can reference the value of the first - see [Creating a cascading list of values](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35125/bldapp_item.htm#CHDJDADC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cascading LOV for select list

the query for the parent select list is as is[STATUS].
while the query for the child should be like this:

edit LOV for EXTRA

```
select solution d, solution r 
from table 
where example = :<ID of parent select list>
```

then put the id of the parent select list into the 
Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)